# Do I need to protect my firebase Server Key? Can I store it in the source code or is there a way to get it programatically?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Right now I have my Server Key for Firebase messaging hardcoded in my code.

Is this a security problem for when I deploy my app?

Can I get this key programatically?

Comment: hardcode in client side code? or on server? If it's on server it should be fine.

Comment: Client. I have no server right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's a security issue, According to this official [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) at the bottom says.

> Important: Do not include the server key anywhere in your client code. Also, make sure to use only server keys to authorize your app server. Android, iOS, and browser keys are rejected by FCM.

And I don't think "get this key programmatically" is good idea because you still downloaded key to the client, or using other way to store in the client.

Comment: This is indeed correct: as its name implies the FCM server key should only be used on a server, or otherwise trusted environment. It doesn't matter *how* you use it in the client, whenever you do that there's a chance a malicious user may take the key, and start sending messages to the users of your app. Have a look at this example of using Cloud Functions to set up a serverless backend to send notifications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to protect in a serious way the key in your apk. Getting the key would be quite easy, so you have a big security issue and your poor security design could have bad conseguences, see for example what GDPR says about privacy. Remove the key, change it if possible and implement a server to communicate with your clients and send push messages.