# Exposed Firebase Cloud Messaging Server Keys

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I had used fcm to send notification in my app using api.after some days google send this and removed my app from play store.please help me.

I have tried everywhere not getting exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put FCM Key in untrusted environment is a security issue, Any hackers are possible to send message to any user by using FCM key.

FCM key shouldn't exists in your public app like downloaded to your instance, Store in local storage, Hardcode inside application etc.

FCM key should only exists in trusted environment like your server, cloud functions etc.

You can also see this [Do I need to protect my firebase Server Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234563/do-i-need-to-protect-my-firebase-server-key-can-i-store-it-in-the-source-code-o/57236672#57236672).